# The definition of a transition matrix and how to find it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose that $\mathcal{V}$ is a nontrivial $n$-dimensional vector
>   space with ordered basis $B$ and $C$. Let $\mathbf{P}$ be the $n
>  \times n$ matrix whose $i\text{th}$ column, for $1 \le i \le n$,
>   equals $[{b}_i]_C$ where $b_i$ is the $ith$ basis vector in $B$. Then
>   $P$ is called the transition matrix from $B$-coordinates to
>   $C$-coordinates.

What I want to understand what $[b_i]_C$ is. Do we first convert every basis vector in $B$ to $C$-coordinates, then put them up as the columns of the matrix $P$? If, say, for example,$\mathcal{V} = \mathbb{R}^3$  $B = \left\{(1,0,-1), (2,1,3), (1,2,5) \right\}$,  and $C =\left\{\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3 \right\}$ what's the process of finding $[b_i]_C$?

My book seems to suggest that in this case we augment the vectors in $B$  with the identity matrix, but that would just give me the inverse of the matrix that contains the elements of $B$ as columns.

Comment: Fix an ordering for $C$ and express $b_i$ in terms of $C$, then place the coefficients in the column.

Comment: @TokenToucan Than you. Just to be sure that I understand, in the example I've chosen, is it correct to say that in this case the transition matrix is from $B$ basis to standard basis is just the matrix having the elements of $B$ as columns?

Comment: @DeMoivre That’s right.

Comment: @amd Thank you.